# A question about how to pack infinitely many non-overlapping circles into a triangle

Tags: general-topology

Let $T$ be an equilateral triangle. Does there exist a subset $U$ of $T$ such that

- $U$ is the countable union of non-overlapping closed disks and
- the $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure of $U$ is equal to the area of $T$?

I wonder if the limit of the process for constructing a so-called "Apollonian Gasket" inside $T$ could be such a $U$.

Comment: does the set T contain the full triangle? or only the outside ?

Comment: oh, clearly the former

Comment: T contains the full triangle. I should have defined T to be the closed convex hull of an equilateral triangle. Sorry about that

Comment: the disks must be pairwise disjoint?

Comment: What's your definition of a disk?

Comment: A closed disk is the closed convex hull of a circle and in my problem the closed disks must be pairwise non-overlapping (but not necessarily pairwise disjoint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various papers from a few decades ago which compute the Hausdorff dimension of the complement of $U$ in various Apollonian gasket kinds of constructions. If the Hausdorff dimension of the complement of $U$ is $<2$ then that's sufficient to conclude that the Lebesgue measure of the complement of $U$ is zero, and so then yes, $U$ has full Lebesgue measure.

So, for example, in the paper of David W. Boyd entitled "The residual set dimension of the Apollonian packing" (Mathematika 20 (1973), 170-174), I find the assertion that in the case of an equilateral triangle, which is what you are asking about, the complement of $U$ has Hausdorff dimension $log(3)/log(2)$ which is indeed $<2$.

Comment: Are you sure Boyd proves this result for euclidean triangles? I think he is using triangles with circular sides which are pairwise tangent at the vertices.   This is the most natural setting for the Apollonian packings.

Comment: He doesn't say he proves it, he only says, in the 3rd paragraph of the paper, that "The exponent of the osculatory packing in this case [namely the case of the equilateral triangle] is obviously also $log(3)/log(2)$". I presume that "osculatory packing" refers to the packing with circles.

Comment: @Lee Mosher: Many thanks for this information. I chose T to have an equilateral triangle boundary because then T can tile the plane and I was trying to construct a countable union of non-overlapping closed disks that is connected and covers the whole plane except for a set of measure zero. Of course, no such countable union can ever cover the whole plane. The property of being able to tile the whole plane allows the countable union to be connected, if the answer to my question is "yes" and if we are constructing an Apollonian Gasket within T.